# Is there a gcc flag to specify not to compile/link when it's already been specified?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a compile command:

```
gcc -c -Demacs -I. -I../../src -I../lib -I../../lib -pthread -isystem /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -isystem /usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -isystem /usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -isystem /usr/include/dbus-1.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -isystem /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -isystem /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -isystem /usr/include/cairo -isystem /usr/include/pango-1.0 -isystem /usr/include/fribidi -isystem /usr/include/harfbuzz -isystem /usr/include/atk-1.0 -isystem /usr/include/cairo -isystem /usr/include/pixman-1 -isystem /usr/include/uuid -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -isystem /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -isystem /usr/include/libmount -isystem /usr/include/blkid -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/uuid -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -isystem /usr/include/dbus-1.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -isystem /usr/include/libmount -isystem /usr/include/blkid -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -isystem /usr/include/uuid -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng16 -isystem /usr/include/harfbuzz -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/p11-kit-1 -fno-common -W -Wabsolute-value -Waddress -Waddress-of-packed-member -Waggressive-loop-optimizations -Wall -Wattribute-warning -Wattributes -Wbool-compare -Wbool-operation -Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch -Wbuiltin-macro-redefined -Wcannot-profile -Wcast-function-type -Wchar-subscripts -Wclobbered -Wcomment -Wcomments -Wcoverage-mismatch -Wcpp -Wdangling-else -Wdate-time -Wdeprecated -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdesignated-init -Wdisabled-optimization -Wdiscarded-array-qualifiers -Wdiscarded-qualifiers -Wdiv-by-zero -Wdouble-promotion -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicate-decl-specifier -Wempty-body -Wendif-labels -Wenum-compare -Wexpansion-to-defined -Wextra -Wformat-contains-nul -Wformat-extra-args -Wformat-security -Wformat-signedness -Wformat-y2k -Wformat-zero-length -Wframe-address -Wfree-nonheap-object -Whsa -Wif-not-aligned -Wignored-attributes -Wignored-qualifiers -Wimplicit -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wincompatible-pointer-types -Winit-self -Wint-conversion -Wint-in-bool-context -Wint-to-pointer-cast -Winvalid-memory-model -Winvalid-pch -Wlogical-not-parentheses -Wlogical-op -Wmain -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmemset-elt-size -Wmemset-transposed-args -Wmisleading-indentation -Wmissing-attributes -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wmissing-profile -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmultichar -Wmultistatement-macros -Wnarrowing -Wnested-externs -Wnonnull -Wnonnull-compare -Wnull-dereference -Wodr -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wopenmp-simd -Woverflow -Wpacked -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wpacked-not-aligned -Wparentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wpointer-compare -Wpointer-sign -Wpointer-to-int-cast -Wpragmas -Wpsabi -Wrestrict -Wreturn-local-addr -Wreturn-type -Wscalar-storage-order -Wsequence-point -Wshift-count-negative -Wshift-count-overflow -Wshift-negative-value -Wsizeof-array-argument -Wsizeof-pointer-div -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wstringop-truncation -Wsuggest-attribute=format -Wsuggest-attribute=malloc -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-final-methods -Wsuggest-final-types -Wswitch-bool -Wswitch-unreachable -Wtautological-compare -Wtrampolines -Wtrigraphs -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas -Wunused -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wunused-macros -Wunused-result -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable -Wvarargs -Wvariadic-macros -Wvector-operation-performance -Wvolatile-register-var -Wwrite-strings -Walloc-size-larger-than=9223372036854775807 -Warray-bounds=2 -Wattribute-alias=2 -Wformat-truncation=2 -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wnormalized=nfc -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wstringop-overflow=2 -Wvla-larger-than=4031 -Wredundant-decls -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-override-init -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-type-limits -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-format-nonliteral -g3 -O2 ../../src/xfns.c
```

But I want to append the `-H` flag (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) since that's the only information that I'm interested in (but I need to keep the state of the original compile command).

So is there a way to prevent compilation in this command, even though I already specified to do so? Like is there another flag I could append (or prepend) that basically says, "I know I specified this, but ignore it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-o /dev/null` to discard the output altogether, or you could send it to a temporary file which you then delete. If you're concerned with compile times, you can add `-E` in order to only run the preprocessor, which is the minimum in order for `-H` to work. That works because if you tell gcc to stop after preprocessing (`-H`), it doesn't matter if you also tell it to stop after creating an object file (`-c`). (That's an exception to the general rule that gcc uses the last of a set of conflicting options, which is designed to let you override options by adding to the end of a command-line.)

However, I can't help thinking that this is not really the best solution to your problem. It seems like you've hand-crafted a compiler invocation with a number of options, and then put it somewhere where it's difficult to modify. A better solution would be to use a makefile and set the value of the various standard makefile variables -- such as `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS` -- which are documented in the [Gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables). In simple cases, your `Makefile` might consist only of lines which set these variables, since Gnu make has built-in rules for common targets.